# Scraping prices from an amazon page with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here is my code sofar

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

PATH="C:/Users/mrcdi/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
url="https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00CDD2GU4"
driver.get(url)
price=driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-offscreen").text
print("here is the price ", price)
```

And here what the return is

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51372/devtools/browser/425a41bc-518b-495b-b70a-72a7e6952f5a 
here is the price
```

And here the html code
[image]

Can please someone help me?

Comment: what exactly is the problem that you have ?  were are you stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to first convert an HTML page into a SOUP or LXML object.
I generally prefer the lxml library since I can use xpath to get element attributes, which is more accurate.

You can start by installing lxml -

```
pip install lxml
```

Start by importing:

```
import lxml.html as html
```

then use this to make Lxml object and pass xpath -

```
doc = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
price = doc.xpath(price_xpath)
```

and you can get the xpath of the price from the dev console, or you can build one like this:

```
//*[@class="price-class-name-here"]//text()
```

Comment: How should this solve my problem?

Comment: You are having issues with getting price information right?

Comment: yes @Paritosh Tripathi

Comment: then try above method